# Siddhi Of Assuming Any Form You Wish

Tags: siddhi, yogi

Seeking some factual info re supernatural abilities. So guys so while trying to awkwardly write an answer on here yesterday I referenced Hindu text Uddhav Gita. In particular the Krishn dialogue in Uddhav Gita about siddhi to take any form you wish.

But then I realized I don’t even know exactly how does this siddhi work, even though I have come across it many times in descriptions of Hanuman (NavNidhi AshthSiddhi) and in so many Tantra texts.

My question : Being able to assume any form, does this mean the yogi can assume any form he wishes for any length of time he wants ?

So if yogi has this siddhi, he could turn himself into a lizard, or a lady, or a tree or whatever, for fifty years if he wants ?

Having this siddhi means being able to take on any form for any length of time, would you guys say that’s correct.

Just trying to clarify. Not really sure how any of this stuff works. Thx !

Comment: Welcome To Hinduism Stack Exchange! I think your primary question is to know for howmuch length of time a Yogi can hold assumed form through siddhi, right?

Comment: I think so, and could they hold the assumed form permanently if they wish ? Or would permanent transformation to another form be a different siddhi altogether ?